# Get Write Protection Status using EWFMGR

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-embedded

I need to get the write protection status of C: drive using [`ewfmgr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940853.aspx) and enable the write protection if it is currently disabled.

I understand that the following command can give me the status of C: drive on CMD window

```
ewfmgr c:
```

but how do I store the value in a variable and check if the write proctection is currently disabled?

I need the following (pseudocode):

```
currentStatus = Somehow get the status of C:
if currentStatus = disable
ewfmgr -enable
shutdown -r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell simply pass the output of `ewfmgr C:` through a [`Where-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) filter:

```
ewfmgr c: | Where-Object {
  $_.Trim() -match '^state\s+disabled$'
} | ForEach-Object {
  ewfmgr c: -enable
  shutdown -r
}
```

In batch use [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx) in a [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx) loop:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('ewfmgr c: ^| findstr /i /r /c:"state  *disabled"') do (
  ewfmgr c: -enable
  shutdown -r
)
```

Comment: I tried to use it but the command window quickly appears and disappear (I already have `pause`) and nothing happens.

Comment: The above is PowerShell, not batch. If you want batch, why did you tag your question [tag:powershell]?

Comment: oh am sorry, I am a newbie in this and didn't actually realise the difference.